# Why does my Mac's dock keep automatically hiding when I enter Mission Control?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dock, mission-control

Every time I enter mission control, my dock hides. I'm not pressing anything on my keyboard, so that's not it. I also can't scale my windows past the hidden dock (This might be it just snapping to other windows, but I'm not sure). For some reason, when I restart the dock, the issue stops. Here is a video of it: https://youtu.be/-csDfovYHUI

Comment: how do you enter mission control